# differential equations calculating

Tags: python, math

I need to calculate some phrase as below.

```
d/dx(sin^2(cos(x)) = 2sin(cos(x))*-sin(x)*cos(cos(x))
```

it is differential equations calculating.
each phrase can place in `d(phrase)/dx`.

is this ability in python and if is not, how can I calculate this kind of phrase?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a differential equation, but it is close to an identity -- you got the sign wrong!

Answer (score 4):

See [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/), a symbolic mathematics library.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said. Take a look at SymPy. Here is a code snippet to demonstrate the relevant functions.

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: x = Symbol('x')

In [3]: (sin(cos(x))**2).diff(x)
Out[3]: -2⋅sin(x)⋅sin(cos(x))⋅cos(cos(x))
```